# From stat().st_mtime to datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, stat, pathlib

What is the most idiomatic/efficient way to convert from a modification time retrieved from `stat()` call to a `datetime` object? I came up with the following (python3):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('foo')
path.touch()
statResult = path.stat()
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
modified = epoch + timedelta(seconds=statResult.st_mtime)
print('modified', modified)
```

Seems round a bout, and a bit surprising that I have to hard code the Unix epoch in there. Is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp), i.e.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
...
stat_result = path.stat()
timezone_naive_modified = datetime.fromtimestamp(stat_result.st_mtime)
print('timezone-naive modified datetime: ', timezone_naive_modified)
```

If you wanted `modified` to be a timezone-aware `datetime` you would instead use `datetime.fromtimestamp(stat_result.st_mtime, tz=timezone.utc)`. However, in reality it is misleading to add such unwarranted validation, as not all files in all operating systems are stamped with a UTC datetime when saved. Even if your own OS does so, files can of course come from anywhere. In particular, **FAT-formatted disks use local time**, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times) under "Files Times and Daylight Saving Times". For this reason timezone-naive `datetime`s should never be promoted arbitrarily to timezone-aware ones. That could potentially lead to some completely baffling bugs and anomalies down the line.

Comment: i suggest to add reference for timezone

Comment: How can you justify converting st_mtime, a "naive" POSIX timestamp, into a timezone-aware `datetime.datetime`, with a specific TZ, namely UTC? A file can be saved on one OS and then copied/moved to another... So wouldn't this imply that every way of saving a file in every possible OS took the trouble to stamp with a UTC value?

Comment: @mikerodent, my initial answer doesn't include any information about time-zones.
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39359270/revisions at all. If you check the question that has been asked, you will see that the author is operating in the UTC TZ, so I guess the editor flying-sheep added these parts during edit.

Comment: Rolled back a big and somewhat misleading edit on this highly-voted answer. See the answer below from user mike rodent for the argument (that was previously in this answer) about not converting mtime to a timezone-aware object localized in UTC.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062515/do-unix-timestamps-change-across-timezones/23062640#23062640) for more about why it's ok to convert a file mtime to a UTC datetime. In short, the mtime is measured in seconds-since-the-epoch (no timezone involved in that calculation), and the epoch is defined as being in UTC.

Comment: @ChristianLong You have made a mistake here. That answer you reference is **only about UNIX OSs**. You haven't understood the very simple point I made, and my edit here needs to be restored. NOT ALL OS'S DATESTAMP FILES WITH UTC. This is the case in particular with FAT-formatted disks. See here learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times : "The FAT file system records times on disk in local time." Obviously such files can be distributed anywhere. There is NO guarantee about UTC.

Answer (score 30):

This works for me if you want a readable string:

```
import datetime
mtime = path.stat().st_mtime
timestamp_str = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: nice to change it to standard as ISO 8601 and RFC 3339 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' or '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' more see https://medium.com/easyread/understanding-about-rfc-3339-for-datetime-formatting-in-software-engineering-940aa5d5f68a

Answer (score 0):

`file.stat().st_time` is a POSIX timestamp. It is the very definition of a timezone-naive value.

And a file can be saved on one OS and then copied/moved to another (and to/from one timezone to another).

Unix systems and also NTFS use UTC. But Windows operating with FAT-formatted disks absolutely does not. These machines timestamp using local time: see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times): "The FAT file system records times on disk in local time". Therefore, unless you can be certain that the file you are interested in, and/or all files which could potentially be handled by your code, was/were not last modified on a FAT system, you have no option but to assume that it is timezone-naive.

And usually, for similar reasons, i.e. ignorance concerning when and where the last modification happened, you also will not be able to know the timezone. So much of the time you won't be able to apply a timezone and convert it into a tz-aware `datetime`. Irksome, but that's the reality.

So (most of the time) it is incorrect to transform such values into a timezone-aware value. Instead:

```
naive_last_modif_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(path.stat().st_mtime)
```

It would in fact be plain wrong to permit a false validation (in this case of tz-awareness of a `datetime`) to be slipped in inadvertently like this, and could lead to some serious errors down the line.