# read filenames from a given .txt file python

Tags: python

I am new to python.

I was trying to write a program that will read files from a .txt file.

(that means I have a 'filenames.txt' file and have filenames with their paths in that file)
How can I read those file names from that .txt file and get the date the file was created?

Heres the code I came up with:

```
import sys, os
import pathlib

# list of filenames with their paths separated by comma 
file_list = []  

# input file name which contains list of files separated by \n
with open ('filenames.txt' , 'r+' ) as f :
    list_file = f.readlines().splitlines()

input_list = file_list + list_file  

def file_check(input_list):
    if input_list is none:
      print ("input_list is null")

print (input_list)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need a little more information, what sort of files are listed in that text file? What do you mean by "read"? If they

Comment: You can read [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-file-handling), try to code yourself and ask if you find any errors or unexpected outputs, given no one else have asked a similar question.

Comment: @CapnJack  I have a filenames.txt file that contains bunch of files like follows.

c/users/......... file1.txt
c/users/......... file2.txt
c/users/......... file3.txt

I want my program to read those files using those file paths and return the number of lines in each file.

Comment: Sorry got a call while I was trying to edit my accidentally submitted original comment so I can't fix it now. But I mean to ask: can I assume all the files in this text file are other text files?

Comment: Yes, All files within the filenames.txt are text files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by this you can open a file:

```
file = open('path/to/filenames.txt')
```

assuming data is written one file name per line you can read from your file like this:

```
filename = file.readline()
```

then for knowing the time of creation you can `import os` and use `stat` function. this function will tell you `st_atime` which is last accessed time, `st_mtime` as last modified time and `st_ctime` as creation time. take a look at [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) :

```
import os
stat = os.stat(filename)
creation_time = stat.s_ctime
```

for ommiting whitespaces at the end of the filenames you can use rstip. 
So, altogether it will look like this:

```
import os
file = open('path/to/filenames.txt')
filename = file.readline()
while filename:
    stat = os.stat(filename.rstrip())
    creation_time = stat.st_ctime
    print(creation_time)
    filename = file.readline()
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help But this is the output coming with your code.

1538435352.7896326

1538176072.1286607

1538494272.3550172

Comment: if you want to make the time human readable, you should format it. take a look at the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359245/from-stat-st-mtime-to-datetime

Answer (score 0):

If they are in this format: [filename] [path] on each line i suggest the following:

```
f = open('filenames.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
```

This will read from the file and then split it into lines

```
f = [x.split(' ') for x in f]
```

It is a shorten way of iterating over f which is a list of string and then split each string at the space so it will be [filename, path]

Here things get a little bit complicated:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime
datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime('filenames.txt')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

All the modules used are builtin

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can check file creation time by using:

```
import os, time
time.ctime(os.path.getctime('your_full_file_path'))
```