# timezone.localize doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

Currently, I tried to understand how `timezone.localize` work.

### naive datetime (without timezone information)

Now, I try to create a naive datetime (without timezone information). I assume everything will respect to UTC

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1535500800)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 0, 0)
>>> time.mktime(d.timetuple())
1535500800.0
>>> d.hour
0
```

(Screenshot from https://www.epochconverter.com/ , by using 1535500800 as timestamp. Red rectangles are for UTC timezone)
[image]

---

Everything seems fine. Now, I would like to experiment with `timezone.localize`

---

### datetime with timezone using timezone.localize

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1535500800)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 0, 0)
>>> kl_timezone = timezone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur')
>>> d = kl_timezone.localize(d)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' +08+8:00:00 STD>)
>>> time.mktime(d.timetuple())
1535500800.0
>>> d.hour
0
```

(Screenshot from https://www.epochconverter.com/ , by using 1535500800 as timestamp. Blue rectangles are for Kuala Lumpur timezone)

[image]

The time information highlight in **blue** rectangle is Kuala Lumpur timezone. Hence, I'm expecting after running `d = kl_timezone.localize(d)`, `d.hour` will return 8.

This is because

- Given 1535500800 timestamp, UTC residents treat it as 12:00 am
- Given 1535500800 timestamp, Kuala Lumpur residents treat it as 8:00 am

But, `d.hour` is returning 0, even after I use `kl_timezone.localize(d)`.

Isn't `d.hour` should return 8, because at timestamp 1535500800, Kuala Lumpur is 8:00 am?

Am I having wrong expectation on `timezone.localize`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime.fromtimestamp` actually converts the to a timestamp in your local timezone. To get the timestamp with respect to UTC, you would use [`datetime.utcfromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp). From there, you would make it aware, with `localize` or `replace`. Then, to determine what the time would be in Kuala Lumpur, you would use [`astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> d = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1535500800)  # naive
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 0, 0)
>>> utc_tz = timezone('UTC')
>>> utc_d = utc_tz.localize(d)  # or utc_d = d.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
>>> utc_d
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> kl_tz = timezone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur')
>>> kl_d = utc_d.astimezone(kl_tz)  # convert from UTC to Malaysia
>>> kl_d
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 8, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' +08+8:00:00 STD>)
```

To get back to POSIX timestamp, you would use [`timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)

```
>>> kl_d.timestamp()
>>> 1535500800.0
```

Comment: Ok. I can see using `astimezone` is returning correct hour value. However, I notice the timestamp value changed as well. I do expect timestamp stayed the time - https://gist.github.com/yccheok/673b14af3d8bde75d656a2e2d17dc164 . Isn't the timestamp should stay the same? (Timestamp stays same across different timezone - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062515/do-unix-timestamps-change-across-timezones)

Comment: The timestamp value with respect to UTC timezone would not change, but `mktime` that you used in your example converts it with respect to your *local* time. If you want to convert it to seconds w.r.t to UTC, I would suggest using [`timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) (e.g. `kl_d.timestamp()`)

Comment: Ok. Now I notice that I'm using the wrong way to get timestamp. `kl_d.timestamp()` is the correct way instead of `time.mktime(kl_d.timetuple())`