# python .timestamp() method calcualtes wrong (or the same) unix time for different timezones

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp

My goal is to convert UTM to local time and then to Unix time. 
This is the original time:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(nw_pd_file['datetime(utc)'][0],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Timestamp('2019-04-26 21:38:11')
```

Adding utc info

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(nw_pd_file['datetime(utc)'][0],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tz_localize('UTC')
Timestamp('2019-04-26 21:38:11+0000', tz='UTC')
```

converting to local Alaska time:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(nw_pd_file['datetime(utc)'][0],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert(pytz.timezone("America/Anchorage"))
Timestamp('2019-04-26 13:38:11-0800', tz='America/Anchorage')
```

Up to here all is good. But when I convert the correct local time to unix time,  the restul is in UTC and not in Alaska local time:

```
>>>pd.to_datetime(nw_pd_file['datetime(utc)'][0],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert(local).timestamp()
1556314691.0
```

When it should be

1556314691.0-8*3600=1556285891.0 # 8 for eight hours Alaska daylight time.

In fact, I get the same Unix timestamp independent of the time-zone:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(nw_pd_file['datetime(utc)'][0],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tz_localize('UTC').timestamp()
1556314691.0
```

Is the timestamp() meothod cannot read the timezone correctly?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UNIX timestamp is designed to be timezone independent. See this thread [Do unix timestamps change across timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062515/do-unix-timestamps-change-across-timezones)

Your code convert the same time to two different time zones, but their UNIX timestamps remain the same.