# Estimating timezones using timestamps only?

Tags: javascript, api, timestamp, timezone, travis-ci

I'm using an API to fetch real-time data of commits, and I want to use the timestamp data to very roughly estimate the location of where the commits were pushed from using timezones. I don't have access to the latitude or longitude, only the user's local time during the commit.

Is there a way to convert or filter the timestamp data and match it with the corresponding timezone? I looked into momentjs timezone and other tools but I struggled to find anything helpful.

Thanks for any help

[Example image of timestamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2qEG.png)

Comment: those timestamps are all UTC, how do you propose to guess which timezone the user was in?

Comment: If you have the IP address for each client, you MIGHT be able to guess which timezone their IP address originates from .. there are classes of IP address for which this information doesn't reliably exist, but it'd be a start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do unix timestamps change across timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062515/do-unix-timestamps-change-across-timezones)