# List all timestamps from each timezone

Tags: php, loops, timestamp, timezone

How can I list each timestamp from each timezone. I tried following code:

```
$timezones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();

foreach ($timezones as $timezone) {
  $dt = new DateTime();
  $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
  echo $dt->getTimestamp() . '<br />';
}
```

For now every loop outputs the same timestamp.

Comment: Of course it does. Unix Time is timezone agnostic. That's the entire point of a Unix Timestamp.

Comment: This seems to have been asked many times before, and there is a long thread on unix timestamps here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062515/do-unix-timestamps-change-across-timezones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, a Unix Timestamp is timezone agnostic. That's actually one of the major benefits of Unix Timestamps. They ignore timezones completely :)

In order to see the different timezones effecting the date here you must actually look at the formatted date, not the Unix Timestamp.

```
$timezones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();

foreach ($timezones as $timezone) {
  $dt = new DateTime();
  $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
  echo $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: Unix timestamps don't ignore timezones, they are _always UTC_.

Comment: i.e. they ***ignore*** timezones :) You must read it in context. "*a Unix Timestamp is timezone agnostic*" ... therefore `DateTime` objects will necessarily ignore the `DateTimezone` when giving you the timestamp, because it's not needed since it's always going to be in UTC.

Comment: *Technically*, UTC isn't a time zone but rather a system of timekeeping.  However, in practice, there is always a time zone object or setting that is labeled UTC.  Thus, you are both correct depending on how you look at the problem. :)